# Access to computer to same profile in different ways

Tags: windows-8.1, users

I have windows 8.1 and I have single user in my computer. This user have password for logon. With this user used for remote desktop also so the password is important.
But when I want to access to the computer physically, I don't want to enter the password every time.

My goal is to make access to the computer physically without password, and by remote desktop with password, and in the two ways I want to see the same user profile.

Is it possible to do that? (Maybe merge two users to the same profile? Or make toe computer to remember the password?)

Comment: You can configured Windows to automatically log into the user account.  Using the remote desktop client, by default, would still require the user's password to access it remotely.

Comment: You can set the computer to remember the password to log you in during startup, but when you get logged off by a RDP session, you will need to supply the password to relog at the console.  Concurrent sessions are not supported by windows terminal services outside of the server products, if they were then you could use the autologin method at the console then log the same user into the machine via RDP without the console logging out.

Comment: How can I do that? I want that my user will automatically login without password at start-up. Its exactly what I want.